# Types for flexibly currying functions

Tags: typescript

I want to create a curried function that can either accept an argument in the outer call, or the inner one - but never both/neither (xor). Is such a thing possible? I can't quite figure out how to make it work. The following clearly doesn't work because I'm not passing on any type information to the inner function:

```
const outerFunc:
  | ((outerVar: string) => (innerVar: never) => string)
  | ((outerVar: never) => (innerVar: string) => string) =
  (outerVar?: string) =>
  (innerVar?: string): string =>
    outerVar || innerVar // typescript still thinks this may be undefined

// What should pass:
outerFunc()('foo')
outerFunc('foo')()

// What should fail:
outerFunc('foo')('foo')
outerFunc()()
```

Anyone know any tricks to get this to work using a combination of generics and conditional types or something? Or maybe function overloads?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this without runtime checks to convince the compiler to narrow the type, but I'd love to be proved wrong!

Comment: Beware of using `||` for this purpose - the empty string is falsy, so `outerFunc('')()` will return `undefined`, not a string. If you use `??` then this problem won't occur.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one variant with function overloads:

```
function outerFunc(x: string): () => string;
function outerFunc(): (y: string) => string;
function outerFunc(x?: string): (y: string) => string {
    return (y) => x || y;
}

// What should pass:
outerFunc()('foo')      // OK
outerFunc('foo')()      // OK

// What should fail:
outerFunc('foo')('foo') // Fails: "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1"
outerFunc()()           // Fails: "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0"
```

Answer (score 2):

A parameter of type `never` is not very useful, since it means you cannot call the function; for those cases you want a function with no parameters. Also, what you want here is a function with two [overload signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), so you get a different result depending on if you call it with an argument or not; overloads are an intersection of function types, not a union.

```
function fail(): never {
    throw new Error();
}

function outerFunc(outerVar: string): () => string;
function outerFunc(): (innerVar: string) => string;
function outerFunc(outerVar?: string) {
    return (innerVar?: string) => outerVar ?? innerVar ?? fail();
}

// ok
outerFunc()('foo')
outerFunc('foo')()

// errors, as expected
outerFunc('foo')('foo')
outerFunc()()
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAhjANgCgJQC5FgCmAboQE6IDeAUInYlABZlwDuBh7AomS2TgG5qAX2rVQkWAkRwQUcgDFwETLPlkAaijL4AzlDIwwAczyIciALwA+RPsMmhE6PCRrFynPkxGim7XoGRqZWtvbBTspSbnIekKqx-mQA-IEOITT0iGSEUCBkSD5gflopacHYoTKJpYjJyYi+5LX1yGhY2EKi1AD0PTIA1tTuZErx2JgA5MBwcJPYw4ljKtOz8zhifYjkfLoANIgoutsAHgAOhNCEACaL6stTM3MTq893cSoTC0A)

Comment: I had an unnecessary optional parameter in the second signature before I peeked at your answer, so my answer is now influenced by parts of your answer as well. +1 for you.